# The property 'AcceptButton' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Want to store selected value in combobox in a variable $x, $y and $z but getting below error.

```
The property 'AcceptButton' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:71 char:5
+     $form1.AcceptButton = $OKButton
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:73 char:5
+     $form1.Controls.Add($OKButton)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:74 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Label1)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:75 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Label2)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:76 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Label3)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:77 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox1)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:78 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox2)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:79 char:5
+     $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox3)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:81 char:4
+    $result = $Form1.ShowDialog() |Out-Null
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")  

    $Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form   
    $Form1.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 313)
    $Form1.Text = 'Enter Your Details'
    $Form1.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

#~~< Label CLASSIFICATION 1 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 83)
    $Label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
    $Label.Text = "Location"
    $Label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
    $Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
    #~~< Label CLASSIFICATION 2 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 113)
    $Label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
    $Label1.Text = "Facility"
    $Label1.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
    $Label1.BackColor = "Transparent"
    #~~< Label CLASSIFICATION 3 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 143)
    $Label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
    $Label2.Text = "Allocated by"
    $Label2.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
    $Label2.BackColor = "Transparent"
    #~~< ComboBox 1 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Classarray = @("Delhi","Punjab","UP","Assam","Mumbai","Haryana","MP")
    $Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $Combobox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 83)
    $Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    $Combobox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
    $Combobox1.TabIndex = 5
    ForEach ($Class in $Classarray) {
    $Combobox1.Items.Add($Class)
    } #end foreach
    #~~< ComboBox 2 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Classarray2 = @("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7")
    $Combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $Combobox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 113)
    $Combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1
    $Combobox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
    $Combobox2.TabIndex = 6
    foreach ($Class in $Classarray2) {
    $Combobox2.Items.Add($Class)
     } #end foreach  
    #~~< ComboBox 3 >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    $Classarray3 = @("Team1","Team2")
    $Combobox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $Combobox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 143)
    $Combobox3.SelectedIndex = -1
    $Combobox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
    $Combobox3.TabIndex = 7
    foreach ($Class in $Classarray3) {
    $Combobox3.Items.Add($Class)
     } #end foreach

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Font = 'Calibri, 12.25pt'
    $okButton.Location = '400, 250'
    $okButton.Margin = '5, 5, 5, 5'
    $okButton.Size = '130,40'
    $okButton.BackColor ="LightGray"
    $okButton.ForeColor ="black"
    $okButton.Text = 'Submit'
    $OKButton.DialogResult = 'OK'
    $Form1.AcceptButton = $OKButton

    $Form1.Controls.Add($OKButton)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Label1)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Label2)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Label3)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox1)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox2)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Combobox3)

   $result = $Form1.ShowDialog() |Out-Null

   if ($result -eq 'OK')
{
    $x = $Combobox1.SelectedItem
    $y = $Combobox2.SelectedItem
    $z = $Combobox3.SelectedItem
    Write-Host "Location" $x
    Write-Host "Facility" $y
    Write-Host "Asset" $z
}
Else
{
Exit
}
```

Comment: To save yourself lots of headaches (debug anxiety), never just write a bunch of code and then test it. Take a procedural approach. Do, one segment at a time, make sure you get back what you'd expect then rinse and repeat for subsequent steps.  Your error messages are very specific and point to what you need to correct. It looks like you are coding this by hand, not that there are several (free VS Community edition, a module in the mspowershellgallery and non-free, PoshGUI.com, PSProTools's PSScriptPad) drag-and-drop Winform/WPF visual designers to make this far easier to do.

Comment: Your elements are not properly defined/instantiated and some are not defined/instantiated at all. Hence all the errors you are seeing. Again, keep it simple and use a visual designer. or use one of the hundreds of online samples that have objects you'd want and refactor as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but since you posted code and errors, here is a quick refactor of your code to show where you had issues and potential considerations for fixes.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form1                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form   
$Form1.ClientSize       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 313)
$Form1.Text             = 'Enter Your Details'
$Form1.FormBorderStyle  = 'FixedDialog'
$Form1.StartPosition    = 'CenterScreen'

$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
 
$Label           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 83)
$Label.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
$Label.Text      = 'Location'
$Label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$Label.BackColor = 'Transparent'

$Label1           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 113)
$Label1.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
$Label1.Text      = 'Facility'
$Label1.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$Label1.BackColor = 'Transparent'

$Label2           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(295, 143)
$Label2.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95, 23)
$Label2.Text      = 'Allocated by'
$Label2.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$Label2.BackColor = 'Transparent'

$Combobox1               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$Combobox1.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 83)
$Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
$Combobox1.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
$Combobox1.TabIndex      = 5
$Combobox1.Items.AddRange(@('Delhi','Punjab','UP','Assam','Mumbai','Haryana','MP'))

$Combobox2               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$Combobox2.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 113)
$Combobox2.SelectedIndex = -1
$Combobox2.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
$Combobox2.TabIndex      = 6
$Combobox2.Items.AddRange(@('D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7'))

$Combobox3               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$Combobox3.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400, 143)
$Combobox3.SelectedIndex = -1
$Combobox3.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170, 21)
$Combobox3.TabIndex      = 7
$Combobox3.Items.AddRange(@('Team1','Team2'))

$OKButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,250)
$OKButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,40)
$OKButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Font         = 'Calibri, 12.25pt'
$okButton.Margin       = '5, 5, 5, 5'
$okButton.BackColor    = 'LightGray'
$okButton.ForeColor    = 'black'
$okButton.Text         = 'Submit'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$Form1.Controls.AddRange(
    @(
        $OKButton, 
        $Label, 
        $Label1, 
        $Label2, 
        $Combobox1, 
        $Combobox2, 
        $Combobox3
     )
)

if ($Form1.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')
{
    "Location: $($Combobox1.SelectedItem)"
    "Facility: $($Combobox2.SelectedItem)"
    "Asset   : $($Combobox3.SelectedItem)"
}
Else {Break}

# Results
<#
Location: Delhi
Facility: D1
Asset   : Team1
#>
```